# How can i combine search listview and ListView.OnItemClickListener

Tags: java, android

I have a `search listview`, and i'm trying to combine the search `listview` with `onItemClickListener` using switch case like this. So that a user  can search an item and click it to do another activity.

**Here is sample screen shot**

[image]

**Here is my code**

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    String[] items;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    ArrayList<String> listItems;
    ListView listView;
    EditText editText;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        editText = findViewById(R.id.txtSearch);
        listView = findViewById(R.id.listName);
        initList();
        editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                if(charSequence.toString().equals("")){
                    initList();
                }else{
                    searchItem(charSequence.toString());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

            }
        });

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(listener);




    }


    ListView.OnItemClickListener listener = new ListView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            switch (listView.getSelectedItemPosition()){
                case 0:
                    changeActivity();
                    break;

                case 1:
                    changeActivity();
                    break;

                case 2:
                    changeActivity();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    changeActivity();
                    break;
            }

        }
    };

    public void changeActivity(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class);
        intent.putExtra("Key", "Value");
        startActivity(intent);
    }



    public void searchItem(String textSeache){
        for (String item:items){
            if(!item.contains(textSeache)){
                listItems.remove(item);
            }
        }
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void initList(){
        items = new String[]{"California, USA", "Toronto,  CANADA", "Beijing,  CHINA", "Taipei,   TAIWAN"};
        listItems = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(items));
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.list_item, R.id.txtItem, listItems);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }


}
```

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: in doing so what error you are getting?

Comment: @NoumanCh 
I am not getting any error, but the app don't work

Comment: your search is working?

Comment: @NoumanCh
Yes, my search is working

Comment: means the issue is your click event is not working isn't it?

Comment: What you want to do for the selected position

Comment: @NoumanCh
Yes, probably is not working

Comment: @AbuYousuf
I want to pass 2 data information into another activity, but this was just for tested to see if the item is clickable

Comment: post your adapter class as well

Comment: post your list_item.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly use the code in Your **`onItemClickListener`** as,

```
String selected = listitems.get(position) ;//or (String)parent.getItemAtPosition(position); 
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class);
intent.putExtra("Key", selected);
startActivity(intent);
```

I think, *switch cases are not needed*, since you just want to move to next activity.

And also *check your list_item.xml layout* since the textview may not be clickable or not be focused.

Comment: I followed your code and did check the xml file, but unfortunately it still crashed when i try to clicked the item

Comment: Can you please post your crash detail

Comment: ***Here is the error message***
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                           Process: com.welsen.searchlistview, PID: 11488
                                                                           java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView

Comment: (String)parent.getItemAtPosition(position); will also work

Comment: or simply use listitems.get(position)

Comment: Yes, it works, but is it possible that i lock a specific value to one item ?

Comment: I didn't get you? can you please explain "i lock a specific value"

Comment: I mean apply a specific value to one specific item,

Comment: Now you can use switch case for the strings you have. And use different value to diff strings or positions

Comment: Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

Add this code snippet of code below `listview.setAdapter(adapter)` and remove `listview.setOnItemClickListener(listener);`

```
 listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                    long id) {

                String item = ((TextView)view).getText().toString();

                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), item, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        });
```

and to pass data to next activity you                         `changeActivity(); should look like this:

```
public void changeActivity(){

Intent intent = new Intent(currentActivity.this,NextActivity.class);
intent.putString("key","value");
startActivity(intent);
}`
```

Comment: I have tried your method, the app did not crash, but when i click the item
it's still not doing anything...

Comment: I have added my full activity on top

Comment: @ NoumanCh
I have tried to follow the code, but the app crashed. Just a question, is it possible to tag in every list item and make every item have it's individual mission ?

Comment: yes this is possible you can play with position of list item. if(position==0){//do something related to position 9}else if(position==1){//do task for postion 1}

Comment: **Here is the crash reason**

FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                         Process: com.welsen.searchlistview, PID: 8673
                                                                         java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView
                                                                             at com.welsen.searchlistview.MainActivity$2.onItemClick(MainActivity.java:61)

Comment: I actually can go to another activity if i used Tag, but my problem is that like: CANADA stands for TAG 0, but when i use search to filter out others list item and get an specific item like CHINA and CHINA was represent TAG 3 but after filtering CHINA will be TAG 1, how can i lock one specific value to one item?

Comment: dear instead of using String type in ArrayList use custom Adapter with custom object type and store the tag with it. public class Coutry{String name;int tag;} where name represent your country name like China etc and tag represent your value of tag.